# how to send the searched string completely to google search (Qt)?

Tags: c++, qt

I send the url to find the page what I need. Hovewer there is a misunderstanding with google.

```
QString baseurl("http://blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch?hl=tr&ie=UTF-8&q=C++");
```

I send searched string q=C++; but google search the string only C, it does not search C++.
What to do for change the searching key C to C++ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing at least the query part of the url to `QUrl::toPercentEncoding`.

Even better, try:

```
QUrl url("http://blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch");
url.addQueryItem("hl", "tr");
url.addQueryItem("ie", "UTF-8");
url.addQueryItem("q", "c++");
QByteArray baseurl = url.toEncoded();
```

Comment: it doesn't make any change in search result. It still search only include C, not C++.

Comment: Something must be mangling the url. `http://www.google.com.sg/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=c%2B%2B` is what I get typing 'c++' directly into the google search page, and it's fine.

Comment: I get typed directly into codes but the result same :( it doesn't change.

Comment: It seems the problem is not related to this bit of code. Maybe you can post some of the other stuff?

Comment: I do it like that;

QUrl url = QUrl::fromEncoded("http://blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch?hl=tr&ie=UTF-8&q=C%2B%2B&&output=rss"); url.addQueryItem("num", "1"); url.addQueryItem("start" ,QString::number(randomValue)); view->load(url);

Comment: Can you perhaps do a `qDebug() << url;` or something and see that it has not decoded your url?